# Character Generation for WFRP Hogshead edition

Tags: tools, books, wfrp-1e, wfrp-2e

My gaming group pulled out some old books, and we found Warhammer Fantasay RP.  The book was published in 1995, and the owner thought it was second edition. Wikipedia tells us it's first edition.

Does anyone know of any online character generators or related player info online for this particular edition of the game? 
What is the official name of this edition, and what should I be searching for online to find material for this edition, but not others?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer in First Part

### System Title

All editions are known as Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay. The first edition, hereafter 1E, is often seen using a separator is logos for "Role•Play". Online resources will often make the distinction for you with numerical notations.

### Online 1E CharGen and resources

While I'm *unsure* of online 1E character generators, 1E was released in 1986 and rereleased by Hogshead at the very cusp of online resources like the WWW, they may be tough to find, and when found, horribly written by today's web standards.

Consider joining the [Strike-to-Stun](http://www.strike-to-stun.net) forums for 1E if seeking a deeper availability of resources.

Also, [MadAlfred's WFRP Pages](http://madalfred.darcore.net) contains some of the richest resources for 1E still online (including two 1E conversions of Druidic and Elemental magic for 2E.)

## Answer in Second Part

WFRP 2E, or second edition, was released, in 2005. It is almost fully compatible with 1E  with the following distinctions:

### Character Builds

Gone is the 1E assumed compatibility with Warhammer Fantasy Battle. All stats are computed on a percentile system. However, the compatibility between 1E and 2E is an easily managed task.

Other mechanical changes address odd "munchkin" builds of dwarf PCs, e.g., the aforementioned "Naked Dwarf" problem.

### Career Changes

The central feature of WFRP 1E, the Career System, largely remains intact in 2E, except in Magical (Arcane) and Clerical (Divine) career paths...

### Magic System Overhaul

Gone are is the tiered levels of arcane and divine magic careers. These careers are aligned mechanically with all other careers in the system.

The new magic system use the unified target number mechanic, ties well with the skill and talent system throughout, provides for dramatic grim failure, and reagents.

### Canon Changes

1E is set during a rising tide of Chaos incursions and plots by Ruinous Powers. Ostensibly,
2E is set following the Storm of Chaos, a Warhammer world event that was played out around the world by Warhammer Fantasy Battle players, that also dovetails with the conclusion of *original* [*The Enemy Within*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enemy_Within_Campaign) campaign.

### Conversion from 1E to 2E resources

Finally, [Liber Fanatica](http://www.liberfanatica.net) has rich, downloadable conversion and support information for 1E-to-2E conversion. LF's Volume 1, [*The Character Compendium*](http://www.liberfanatica.net/LF1download.html) was compiled by play-testers of 2E and contains details on converting your 1E PCs to 2E.

These conversion tools would be very helpful if you wanted to say chargen using the 1E ruleset on hand and purchase 2E material at a later date.

### Availibility of WFRP 2E

Almost all 2E material is now available for purchase at [DriveThru RPG as PDF](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/index.php?cPath=36_4943&affiliate_id=188022) (and some titles as Print-on-Demand).

Hope this helps... 1E resources are out there, but show their age (if not in web design alone; remember 1E was released in 1986 and Al Gore didn't invent the internet until at least 1992--at least that's when he co-sponsored public access to ARPANET in the US Congress).

Taken from  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19393/2064

I've never encountered a character generator that wasn't hit by a "Cease & Desist" letter from GW. All of the ones I've seen have been removed from the net.

IDing 1E materials

In general, all you need to look at is the publisher. If it was Games Workshop, Citadel, Hogshead Productions, or Warpstone Magazine (to issue 22), it's for 1E.

If the publisher is Black Industries or Fantasy Flight Games, it's not for 1E.

WFRP 2E setting materials can be converted with only minor difficulties, but character and monster conversions may result in some odd issues.

WFRP 3E materials are mechanically totally incompatible

Comment: I'm having a hard time marking any answer correct, this one and "WFRP 1E - Games Workshop and Hogshead Productions", combined answered my question.

Comment: Thanks @GMNoob [see this meta question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/what-to-do-when-theres-more-than-one-good-answer#answer-1141) for ideas on accepting an answer

Comment: while I marked this answer as correct, http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19393/2064 gave invaluable information which I would not have gotten from this answer alone.  http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19393/2064

Comment: Why is there a downvote? Is there something wrong here that I should be aware about?

Comment: There is a species of RPG SE user and moderator that harbors a kind of "I'll piss on this poster, his/her comments and answers" out of spite or jealously. You certainly have seen it before, I know I have.

Answer (score 4):

## WFRP 1E - Games Workshop and Hogshead Productions

WFRP 1E comprises 3+ printings.

- GW 1st Printing, Hardcover. Major errata issues
- GW 2nd Printing, Softcover. Minor errata issues; most of the 1st ed 1st printing errors got fixed. GW may or may not have run a 3rd printing, but if they did, it was using the same plates.
- HHP Printings, softcover. Exact reprint of GW 2nd printing, including all mistakes; differences are visible only in some of the art, and on the back cover logos.

As long as you don't have the hardcover, the rules content is identical across the rest.

The setting is roughly contemporaneous to WFB 2E's setting, but gets advanced by later HHP releases.

The line ended when Hogshead returned the rights to Games Workshop.

There are two GW rules addenda books, plus some additional mechanics buried in the adventures. The WFRP Companion and the Character Pack are the two. While the Character pack included character sheets, it was much sought for the additional character generation materials. (No, you can't have mine!)

There was additional material in the WFB Realms of Chaos books, but it's only useful if you want to include major chaos nastiness. And at the prices they go for, they're frightfully hard to legally obtain. (No, you can't have mine!)

HHP added several more rules addenda books: Apockrypha Now (which mostly replaces the WFRP Companion), Apochrypha 2 Chart of Darkness, the GM Screen (expanded crits and fumbles), Dwarves: Stone and Steel (Dwarven racial book - the elven one was vaporware), and Realms of Sorcery.

I've never encountered a character generator that wasn't hit by a "Cease & Desist" letter from GW. All of the ones I've seen have been removed from the net.

## IDing 1E materials

In general, all you need to look at is the publisher. If it was Games Workshop, Citadel, Hogshead Productions, or Warpstone Magazine (to issue 22), it's for 1E.

If the publisher is Black Industries or Fantasy Flight Games, it's not for 1E.

WFRP 2E setting materials can be converted with only minor difficulties, but character and monster conversions may result in some odd issues.

WFRP 3E materials are mechanically totally incompatible

Comment: We want to play a high death stakes game, and want to be able to randomly create characters quickly. Are you saying there are no tools available for that, or just no free tools?

Comment: No tools that are shareable - The 3 various spreadsheets I've seen hit the net got taken down quickly. Keep in mind - WFRP1E has been out of print for over a decade (2002 was when the license was surrendered), and GW routinely sweeps the net and zipyanks stuff. Your best bet is to write your own. And, given the really trivial amount of coding needed, plus random career selection within class, it's a good beginning coding project. Just don't put it on the net - GW goes psycho over that.

Comment: I'm having a hard time marking any answer correct, this one and "Answer in First Part", combined answered my question.

Comment: @GMNoob [see this meta question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/what-to-do-when-theres-more-than-one-good-answer#answer-1141) for ideas on accepting an answer

Comment: This answer most directly answered my question, however the other answer http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19387/2064 gave me the links which allowed me learn further and answer other questions that quickly arose in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Warhammer Fantasy RP First Edition is called Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay or, retroactively, Warhammer Fantasy RP First Edition. As such, including First Edition is likely to be your best bet. The Hogshead edition is merely a reprint by a separate company.

It's worth knowing that second edition was a change on the level of D&D 3.0 to D&D 3.5, a lot of game mechanical fixes and minor changes, but material for one can easily be adapted to the other, as such most advice for WFRP 2e should be usable for 1e.

One particular issue to watch out for in 1e is the 'Naked Dwarf' issue. With a bit of system knowledge it's fairly easy to make a dwarf which is so hard to hit he doesn't need armor anymore. This is one of the issues that was addressed in 2e.

As 2e was generally an all-around improvement and 95% compatible, there's unfortunately not a lot of material for 1e out there anymore. The biggest site I know of that caters to 1e also caters to 2e and is [Strike to Stun](http://www.strike-to-stun.net/). It's a fan-site and not as active as any official resource, but it should have some resources that could be useful.

In general, only 3e specific resources should be avoided, as 3e is entirely incompatible with 2e and before, while 1e and 2e need a small amount of conversion at worst when going from one to the other.