# How can I update my WFRP 1e character to 2e?

Tags: wfrp-2e, wfrp-1e

We have been playing a WFRP 1e game for many months now, my character has already gone through 3 or 4 careers.

We have decided as a group to switch to WFRP 2e rules.  But we are not sure how to go about doing it.  The GM has decided that he does NOT want to just say we have X amount of XP so make a new char, but rather wants to port the character over with some clear and balanced guidelines.

How do we make that transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Taken from an answer given to an unrelated question here:](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19387/2064)

> ### Conversion from 1E to 2E resources
>
> Finally, [Liber Fanatica](http://www.liberfanatica.net/) has rich, downloadable conversion and
>   support information for 1E-to-2E conversion. LF's Volume 1, [The
>   Character Compendium](http://www.liberfanatica.net/LF1download.html) was compiled by play-testers of 2E and
>   contains details on converting your 1E PCs to 2E.
>
> These conversion tools would be very helpful if you wanted to say
>   chargen using the 1E ruleset on hand and purchase 2E material at a
>   later date.

The Character conversion rules start on page 38 of [this PDF](http://www.liberfanatica.net/liber.fanaticaI.pdf)